# Reading a value from XML

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have the following XML

```
  <applicationSettings>
<CR.Properties.Settings>
  <setting name="AllowSslTrustAll" serializeAs="String">
    <value>False</value>
  </setting>
  <setting name="SyncInterval" serializeAs="String">
    <value>30</value>
  </setting>
  <setting name="SyncServiceToken" serializeAs="String">
    <value>1597538520147</value>
  </setting>
  <setting name="SyncServiceUrl" serializeAs="String">
    <value>http://cr.myurl.com:4012/-cr/DataService.svc</value>
  </setting>
  <setting name="SaveChangesOptions" serializeAs="String">
    <value>Batch</value>
  </setting>
</CR.Properties.Settings>
```

I am trying to place the SyncServiceToken into a string and I appear to be failing miserably at it.

My current code is this:

```
        Dim XMLpath As String = "C:\temp\CR.SyncClient.exe.config"
    Dim SyncToken As String = Nothing

    Dim xml = XDocument.Load(XMLpath)
    TextBox1.Text = xml.Document.<applicationSettings>.<CR.Properties.Settings>.Elements("SyncServiceToken").Value
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try xml linq

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim xml As String = _
            "<applicationSettings>" & _
                "<CR.Properties.Settings>" & _
                    "<setting name=""AllowSslTrustAll"" serializeAs=""String"">" & _
                        "<value>False</value>" & _
                    "</setting>" & _
                    "<setting name=""SyncInterval"" serializeAs=""String"">" & _
                        "<value>30</value>" & _
                    "</setting>" & _
                    "<setting name=""SyncServiceToken"" serializeAs=""String"">" & _
                        "<value>1597538520147</value>" & _
                    "</setting>" & _
                    "<setting name=""SyncServiceUrl"" serializeAs=""String"">" & _
                        "<value>http://cr.myurl.com:4012/-cr/DataService.svc</value>" & _
                    "</setting>" & _
                    "<setting name=""SaveChangesOptions"" serializeAs=""String"">" & _
                        "<value>Batch</value>" & _
                    "</setting>" & _
                "</CR.Properties.Settings>" & _
            "</applicationSettings>"

        Dim settings As XElement = XElement.Parse(xml)
        Dim SyncServiceToken As String = settings.Descendants("setting").Where(Function(x) CType(x.Attribute("name"), String) = "SyncServiceToken").FirstOrDefault()
    End Sub

End Module
```